# extract raw image data but result is out of expect

Tags: c++, image, file, fread, fseek

I am using C++ to extract the raw image data.
[image: 1280x800 area is what I want]

But here comes a trouble.
I use either `fseek` or `fread` functions to move the file pointer, but both results are out of my expectation. 
It seems the pointer is not the location which I want to move to. 
Could someone give me a hint?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int IMAGE_WIDTH=1280;
int IMAGE_HEIGHT=800;
int size=1280*800*2;
int header=128;
int line_padding=0;

int main()
{
    FILE* fd;
    FILE* fd_bin;
    char *temp = (char*)malloc(size);
    char *dat = (char*)malloc(size);

    if (!dat) {
        perror("malloc");
        return NULL;
    }


    fd = fopen("original.raw", "rb");
    if (!fd) {
        printf("File Read Fail...\n");
        exit(1);
    }

//    fseek(fd, header, SEEK_SET);
        fread(temp, 1, header, fd);

    for(int k=0;k<IMAGE_HEIGHT;k++)
    {
        fread(dat, 1, IMAGE_WIDTH*2, fd);
        //fseek(fd , line_padding*2, SEEK_CUR);
                fread(temp, 1, line_padding*2, fd);
    }


/////////////////////////////Save bin
    fd_bin = fopen("output.raw", "wb");
    if (!fd_bin) {
        printf("File Open Fail...\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    fwrite( dat, 1, IMAGE_WIDTH*IMAGE_HEIGHT*2, fd_bin);

    fclose(fd_bin);
///////////////////////////////////////////
    fclose(fd);

    free(temp);
    free(dat);
}
```

Comment: This code seems C++ because the return values of `malloc()` are casted. But why not use `new[]`?

Comment: You want to move the file pointer by 0 bytes to skip the dummy data? Pleayse describe your "my expectation".

Comment: `fread(dat, 1, IMAGE_WIDTH*2, fd);` is overwriting the first line of `dat` with each line of data. Perhaps you need `fread(dat + k*IMAGE_WIDTH*2, 1, IMAGE_WIDTH*2, fd);` instead.

Comment: As @MikeCAT tries to explain, `line_padding` is still zero.

Comment: Why are you not using your debugger to see these obvious issues (such as line_padding being 0)?

Comment: Sorry, line_padding should be 8... (I change to 0 for debugging)

Comment: @Ian Abbott That's the point, I get it. Thank you very much,